# Multidimensional array indexing using pointer to elements

Tags: c++, c++11

As far as I know, multidimensional array on stack will occupy continuous memory in row order. Is it undefined behavior to index multidimensional array using a pointer to elements according to ISO C++ Standard? For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
  int a[5][4]{{1,2,3,4},{},{5,6,7,8}};
  constexpr auto sz = sizeof(a) / sizeof(std::remove_all_extents<decltype(a)>::type);
  int *p = &a[0][0];
  int i = p[11];  // <-- here
  p[19] = 20;  // <-- here
  for (int k = 0; k < sz; ++k)
    std::cout << p[k] << ' ';  // <-- and here
  return 0;
}
```

Above code will compile and run correctly if pointer does not go out of the boundary of array `a`. But is this happen because of compiler defined behavior or language standard? Any reference from the ISO C++ Standard would be best.

Comment: Well I couldn't find anything directly linked from the ISO C++ Standard. But yes, automatically allocated arrays are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in memory. And when you use the index operator i.e. `p[11]` on a simple pointer it's equivalent to `*(p+11)`, so if there is legitimate data of type `*p` the behaviour is defined.

Comment: @George Layout guarantees and legal access are not the same things.  Don't confuse implementation with abstraction requirements.

Comment: I think `[expr.add]/5` might forbid this but `[dcl.array]/1` does guarantee that the storage is contiguous.

Comment: @Yakk it's self evident from definition of pointer increment and of index operator. Technically, C++ standard guarantees that, just  you need be a lawyer to read that properly. Multidimensional array is array of arrays (of arrays, and so on). So incrementing index of array leads to increment equal to size of array's element that is sub-array element  times length of sub-array.. and so on recursively

Comment: @Swift No, access past the end of any array is not legal.  Even if you know what is there.

Comment: @Yakk And there is no access past end of array, where you saw it? *(k+6) points at seventh object in array of  int, while our array declared as array of 20 ints

Comment: @Swift there is an array of 4 arrays of 5 ints.  There is no variable of type `int[20]`: an array of 20 ints.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is the *strict aliasing rule* that exists in my draft n3337 for C++11 in 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval] § 10. This is an exhaustive list that does not explicetely allow to alias a multidimensional array to an unidimensional one of the whole size.

So even if it is indeed required that arrays are allocated consecutively in memory, which proves that the size of a multidimensional array, say for example `T arr[n][m]` is the product of is dimensions by the size of an element: `n * m *sizeof(T)`. When converted to char pointers, you can even do arithmetic pointer operations on the whole array, because any pointer to an object can be converted to a char pointer, and that char pointer can be used to access the consecutive bytes of the object (*).

But unfortunately, for any other type, the standard only allow arithmetic pointer operations inside one array (and *by definition* dereferening an array element **is the same** as dereferencing a pointer after pointer arithmetics: `a[i]` **is** `*(a + i)`). So if you both respect the rule on pointer arithmetics and the strict aliasing rule, the global indexing of a multi-dimensional array is not defined by C++11 standard, unless you go through char pointer arithmetics:

```
int a[3][4];
int *p = &a[0][0]; // perfectly defined
int b = p[3];      // ok you are in same row which means in same array
b = p[5];          // OUPS: you dereference past the declared array that builds first row

char *cq = (((char *) p) + 5 * sizeof(int)); // ok: char pointer arithmetics inside an object
int *q = (int *) cq; // ok because what lies there is an int object
b = *q;            // almost the same as p[5] but behaviour is defined
```

That *char pointer arithmetics* along with the fear of breaking a lot of existing code explains why all well known compiler silently accept the aliasing of a multi-dimensional array with a 1D one of same global size (it leads to same internal code), but technically, the global pointer arithmetics is only valid for char pointers.

---

(*) The standard declares in 1.7 The C++ memory model [intro.memory] that

> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte... The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every
>   byte has a unique address.

and later in 3.9 Types [basic.types] §2

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object
>   holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes making up the object can be copied into an array
>   of char or unsigned char.

and to copy them you must access them through a `char *` or `unsigned char *`

Comment: I think there is technically no aliasing there.  We have a pointer to the first element of an array of size 5 in `int*p`.  I suppose you are saying if a pointer to `T[a][b]` was guaranteed to legal to alias into a pointer to `T[a*b]` the operation would be implicitly legal?

Comment: what limits it to only char pointer arithmetic? in your example (((char *) p) + 5 * sizeof(int)) might be legal on any platform, but if  there is mistake in math that would move increemt off address that matches beginning of int element, on platform with strict data alignment, e.g. SPARC, that will cause disastrous situation, it's an illegal opcode. Standard should pursue more streamlined and universally working path, why it cannot be *(p+5) ?

Comment: @Yakk: What I say is that `a[i]` is legal only if `a` and `a+i` point inside the same array. And it would be the case if we could alias `T[a][b]` and `T[a*b]`. But I agree with you the legality of aliasing the pointers would be enough.

Comment: @Swift: I do not want to argue whether the standard should or should not allow this or that. I only say that *bytes* are a special case that give access to the *representation* of trivially copyable objects...

Comment: It does sound funny that standard declares fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte, because it's not true for quite a number of existing platforms where C++ used as programming language. And char isn't byte on all of them. There are platforms where you can't access address that isn't aligned to CPU's word.. or  where that word length is depending on which type is used. If you take array of int and move it one byte forward on such system, the data becomes inaccessible as int values.

Comment: @Swift: what you are speaking of is *alignment*. Some objects may have alignment requirement, but every single byte must have a distinct address. By the way the standard only require that a byte contains at least 7 bits but platforms where a byte uses 12 bits could exist...

Comment: Disagree that the strict aliasing rule prevents this. The lvalue used for access has type `int`, and the memory being accessed each time has type `int`, so there is no violation.

Comment: @Swift `char` is defined as 1 byte by the standard. Usually "1 byte" means the minimum addressable unit of the target system, not necessarily 8 bits which is called "octet".

Comment: @M.M The culprit is indeed the fact that pointer arithmetics are only defined inside an array and in a 2D arrays the arrays of the basic type are thé rows. But if we could alias a multi-D array with a 1D array of global size, pointer arithmetics would be legal on the aliased array.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta but what if one considers 3D array as 2D array where rows are 1D  aliases of 2D arrays?

Comment: M.M: octet on those platform is is one minimal addressable unit. cant perform integer operations with units whose addresses aren't proportional to 16 bytes, what you call alignment in C++. There is analogous case with x86 platforms where addressable units for  SIMD  instructions are 128bit. Char 's sizeof() is defined to be 1 , not to be one 1 byte, it's one addressable unit.   there must be defined  int8_t (uint8_t) which is exactly 8 bit. Mismatch of  terms of alignment \padding and addressable units when dealing with C++ and with machine code is confusing

Comment: I think maybe you can add 5.7 Additive operators [expr.add]/5 to your answer when explaining that *the standard only allow arithmetic pointer operations inside one array* and *`a[i]` is legal only if `a` and `a+i` point inside the same array*. Then your answer would be more clearly and helpful.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the behavior in your example is technically undefined.

The standard has no concept of a multidimensional array.  What you've actually declared is an "array of 5 arrays of 4 ints".  That is `a[0]` and `a[1]` are actually two different arrays of 4 ints, both of which are contained in the array `a`.  What this means is that `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]` are not elements of the same array.

[expr.add]/4 says the following (emphasis mine)

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>   of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is
>   large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of
>   the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression. In other words, if
>   the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P))
>   and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of the array
>   object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object,
>   the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points
>   one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined**

So, since `p[11]` expands to `*(p + 11)` and since `p` and `p + 11` are not elements of the same array (one is an element of `a[0]` and the other is more than one element past the end of `a[0]`), the behavior of that addition is undefined.

I would, however, be very surprised to find any implementation where such an addition resulted in anything other than the one you expect.

Comment: But wouldn’t `((p + 4) + 4) + 3` be well defined, given that `p + 4` is one past the end of `a[0]`, and also happens to be a pointer to `a[1][0]`? I’m pretty sure the alignment and padding rules guarantee that `sizeof(a[0]) == 4*sizeof(int)` and that `a[1]` is `sizeof(a[0])` bytes after `a[0]`.

Comment: Standard doesn't define multidimensional arry because it is defined recursively. Think of  it like of recursive template. But unlike  class, array guaranteed to be stored in continos manner. Compiler will be right to throw warning if in array of int a[4][5] you try access a[4][0] element... because it would be same as *(a+20), which in this particular case is out of array boundary. It will warn about a[0][6].  Such occurrence may suggest mistake\typo in code. If indexes given runtime, compiler will not know what values are used and usual pointer math will be at work.

Comment: @DanielH Don't confuse implementation with abstraction.  The abstraction states what is required to be defined.  Pointers and array indexing is not defined in terms of a linear memory model in C++.  Instead, various operations are defined.  One way to implement them is with a linear memory model; but even there, optimizers can presume that only defined operations will occur.  A classic example is a union of double and integer: modifying one and then reading the other is UB, even though the bits are guaranteed to be overlapping.

Comment: @Swift Array access is not defined in the standard in terms of a flat, linear memory model.  You are describing why this undefined behavior typically works, not proving it is defined.

Comment: @Yakk Irrelevant example. In case of union result depends on which format platform uses, the bit map of values.  pointer math is abstract enough. It's not describing _how_ actually array is stored in memory, it describes that fact that we can use pointer to iterate through array elements .After all, on many platforms pointer is a structure, not a scalar value , implementation-wise

Comment: @Yakk: I do not fully agree with you: the standard does define that an array is a flat linear sequence of *bytes*. But that does not allow indexing of non character pointers outside of the declared array.

Comment: @Daniel H by the way, padding not applicable to arrays, only to POD structures and unions. Padding rules in this case is "there is no padding"

Comment: @Swift Again, you are talking about implementation.  Implementation is not relevant.  There are operations the standard defines, and the compiler is free to assume that no other operation is done by your code.  If you write to one union element and read to another, that is undefined; as such, the compiler is free to assume (for example) cache the value from an earlier read and skip the next one.  Or prove that your code does UB in that branch, and eliminate the entire branch.  Or shoot nasal demons out your nose.  There are limited legal operations on arrays; anything else is undefined.

Comment: @Yakk yeah, that's one of currently existing defects of standard. It overlooks the fact that code might be reusable, and while one  code will  write to one field, it's safe to assume that output code might be used by someone else that would read from other field (not having access to text of reused code).That situation becomes defined across function calls, but is undefined within single function (because it might be optimized out, cached, etc.)

Comment: @Swift I don't know why you think the situation becomes defined across function calls.  And unless you are going to quote a section of the standard at me directly, I don't care to know your reasoning, but I strongly suspect it is wrong.

Comment: @Swift Union access to the “wrong” member isn’t defined across function calls. If you don’t know what the most recently written member of a union is, reading any of them is undefined in C++. I think C does have it defined explicitly (across function calls or otherwise) and many compilers let you, though.

Comment: @Swift I usually think of alignment and padding as a single issue; padding is inserted to maintain alignment.

Comment: @Yakk I don’t think I was mixing up the standard and the implementation. The standard guarantees that `p + 4` is possible, because it is one past the end of `a[0]`. It guarantees that `(char*)(a[0]) + 4*sizeof(int)` is an equivalent pointer to `(char*)(a[1])`, and since the latter can be converted to an `int*` the former can as well. I *think* that `(int*)((char*)p + 4*sizeof(int))` is equivalent to `p + 4`, but I guess I’m not certain of that. Since the former is a pointer to the first element of `a[1]`, I think the latter is too.

Comment: In both my previous comments I got the order of the sizes confused; please pretend I said `5` everywhere I said `4` (and `((p + 5) + 5) + `, etc.)

Comment: @DanielH reading the most recently written member of a union is not undefined (whether or not you know that that was the most recently written).

Comment: @Daniel H alignment defines where object's address would start (i.e. if alignment is 16, then object's address always will be  times of 16 bytes), while padding are gaps that maintain packing of fields inside of congregate objects (i.e. structs). A struct with non-singular packing still will be misaligned.

Comment: @Swift The reason packing exists is to maintain the alignment of members of aggregate data structures. If alignment weren’t an issue, nobody would have decided that the compiler should automatically decide to put unused bytes into `struct`s.

Answer (score -1):

if you declare

```
int  arr[3][4][5];
```

the type of `arr` is `int[3][4][5]`, type of `arr[3]` is `int[4][5]`, etc. Array of array  of arrays, but NOT an array of pointers. Let's see what happens if we increment first index? It would shift pointer forward by size of array element, but array element of arr is a two-dimensional array! It is equivalent to  incrementing: `arr + sizeof(int[4][5])/sizeof(int)` or arr + 20.

Iterating this way we'll find that `arr[a][b][c]` equals to `*(*(*(arr + a) + b) + c)`, provided that there is never any padding with arrays (to comply with  mandatory compatibility of POD types with C99):

```
*((int*)arr + 20*a +  5*b + c)
```

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, I fixed it, autocorrect added * after nearly every int with [

Comment: The question asks about using an `int` pointer, though, not decaying `arr` to a pointer.

Comment: @Daniel H arr decays to  pointer that points at same object as  pointer    evaluated by &(first of element of arr)

Comment: Right, but the sample code in the question says `int *p = &a[0][0]` (the equivalent in your answer of `int *ptr = &arr[0][0][0]`. That is an `int` pointer.

Comment: `arr[a][b][c]` is `*(*(*(arr + a) + b) + c)`, not what you wrote. `arr + 20` is way out of bounds of `arr`. `arr + 3` is the end of `arr`.

Comment: @ M.M you're right , that's what I meant to write. fighting with phone screen and editor that mistreats those * and ( as formatting tags that  through my train of thought off.  Question was about _casted_ pointer that used as global  iterator of array, in this case its ((int*)arr + index). That's actually common case with with math or 3d APIs, like OpenGL or Direct3D, because those API are C-compatible and use pointers to one-dimensional arrays as matrices.