# Non-typename arguments in angle brackets vs in parentheses

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, arguments

```
// Called with doSomething<5>();
template<unsigned i_>
void doSomething()
{
    std::cout << i_ << '\n';
}

// Called with doSomething(5);
void doSomething(unsigned i_)
{
    std::cout << i_ << '\n';
}
```

When is the first option preferred? Why is it even available? I understand it's useful for classes where the arguments in angle brackets are tied to the object itself, not a specific constructor, but is it useful for functions?

Comment: I believe you just found template metaprogramming - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming (:

Comment: This question is really broad, but how about a simple example: `std::array<int, i_> arr;`

Comment: And I gave an example for the function template you defined above. You're not going to find any case where they differ in capabilities when all you do is use the parameter for a runtime use. How about another example with no classes anywhere? `static_assert(i_ < 10);`

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood it. Couldn't you do that with `const` or `constexpr` too, though?

Comment: @chris `The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.` — [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). But I guess it's another way

Comment: Not as a function parameter. `constexpr` makes a function usable at both compile-time *and* runtime. If you do something only allowed at compile-time, you can't currently use it (at least not directly).

Comment: @Jezor: Not every use of templates is "metaprogramming".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you want to call it. If you use the `template` version then `i_` has to be known at compile time. It's more useful in other examples like if you'd like to perform some other operations which need information at compile time. Furthermore - every different use of it creates a new function.

```
template<unsigned i_>
void doSomething() {
    static int a = 0;
    std::cout << a++ << std::endl;
}
```

For the input:

```
doSomething<1>();
doSomething<1>();
doSomething<1>();
doSomething<2>();
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
0
```

As if there was another function. A useful example would be passing a 2D array of compile-time known size into the function.

```
template<unsigned n>
void doSomething(int (*array)[n]) {
  // ...
}
```

The second one, on the other hand, operates on the same function and the information does not have to be provided at compile-time. So basically the code:

```
void doSomething(unsigned i_) {
    static int a = 0;
    std::cout << i_ << " " << a++ << '\n';
}
```

used as:

```
doSomething(1);
doSomething(1);
doSomething(1);
doSomething(2);
```

gives the output:

```
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 3
```

The array example would be like this:

```
void doSomething(int (*array)[5]) {
  // ...
}
```

which restricts you only to nx5 matrices (where n is a particular number), and for every dimension you'd have to overload the function by hand. Templates provide you an elegant way to let the compiler do it for you.

To sum it up - the first method creates a new function each time a different set of parameters is given and they have to be known at compile time and the second one creates just one function and operates on it.

Comment: The slight problem with the array parameters is that a top level array in a parameter is adjusted to a pointer, so those are equivalent to `int(*array)[n]` and `int(*array)[5]`.

Comment: I'd argue about that. 2D arrays given like in my example are just one-dimensional with some code sugar, but in your example they're a pointer to a `n` or `5` dimensional array.

Comment: the *array parameter* must be written as `int (&array)[m][n]` in order to work, as arrays **cannot** be passed by value in C++. What you have written will decay, as chris has explained in the first comment.

Comment: The array example is bad and very misleading, because the first dimension is practically **discarded**. Which means that, for example, the following code compiles fine: `int array[1][5]; doSomething<3, 5>(array);`.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189577/multidimensional-array-indexing-using-pointer-to-elements) in regard to treating it as 1D. It's laid out like that in memory, but there's another issue.

Comment: You're right - I changed it to the proper way of doing it.