# how can i fill a matrix in c++ with a value?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have a matrix of size `a` and `b` .

`int matrix [a] [b]`

How can i fill it with any value ?

Thank you for responding to my question .

Comment: Use a nested loop.

Comment: Like this:  `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) matrix[i][j] = 0;`

Answer (score 4):

You tagged C++14 so you can use a doubled ranged loop

```
for ( auto & v : matrix )
   for ( auto & e : v )
      e = 42;
```

It seems to me a simple and elegant way to initialize `matrix`.

Just for fun, I show you a way using the standard algorithms

```
std::for_each(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix),
   [](auto & v){ std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 42); });
```

Other ways are possible (see, by example, the `std::fill()` only solution in the Vlad's answers) but I find the nested double for more elegant and simple to understand.

Remember that if you have to initialize to zero, you can simply write

```
int matrix [4][2] { };
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplest way is to interpret the two-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array and apply the standard algorithm `std::fill`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 5;
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[M][N];

    std::cout << "Enter the initializer value: ";
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;

    std::fill( *a, *a + M * N, value );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the initializer value: 10
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Comment: Very nice (and when I try something similar I ever make mistakes with pointers). But (IMHO) you should add a little explanation regarding `std::fill( *a, *a + M * N, value );`

Comment: this is mistake, you have to do additional actions to work with two dimensional array... `std::fill` not guaranteed to work so, because `*a` is array of arrays, so increment of it would point to next line of matrix.  *From ISO standard's point of view expression* `*a+M*N` is pointer to location outside of array bound by much, because last element of that array is `*a + N - 1`.

Comment: @Swift - "because `*a` is array of arrays", ehmm... no; as far I know, `a`, not `*a`, is an array of arrays and is equiparable to a pointer to pointer; so `*a` is equiparable to a simple pointer (to `int`, in this case); so (taking in count that arrays of array are sequential in memory) `*a+M*N` should be the **first** location outside `a`, not outside by much. I see the defect in Vlad's answer that is a little obscure for a novice (and, IMHO, dangerous also for an expert); but is seems to me that is correct.

Comment: @max66 implementation-wise it is likely correct, in standard it's an UB though. I meant `a`, not `*a`. `*a` is pointer to first row, `int[N]`. From C++ memory model's view `*a+M*N` isn't pointing to element behind whole array, it points to M*N-th element after in first row of matrix. With how it is used now, we don't have guarantee how compiler would implement  storage for a[M][N], we never take address of anything.

Comment: @Swift You are wrong. In this expression * a+M*N * a is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. That is the expression * a has the type int[10[ that is converted to the type int * in the expression * a + M*N

Comment: Logically it's correct but there is no guarantee. there were long -winded discussions on SO before on this matter.. thing is that treating multidimensional array as single-dimensional is UB, nothing more. just like reading from element of union that wasn't written to. double ranged offered by max guaranteed to generate code equivalent to what you want to happen here

Comment: @Swift - please, can you give us some link to this "discussions on SO"?

Comment: @max66 for example, accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189577/multidimensional-array-indexing-using-pointer-to-elements/41190113#41190113 Yes, what I wrote works, because compiler s try not to break existing code., but Vlad's case obfuscates it even further and relies on implementation of std::fill (might not work with some more complex type) and apparently creates less effective code than double for-loop. Also this is the kind of code that expresses author's hate toward anyone who would maintain it :P

Comment: @Swift - thanks for the link; now I have a lot to read the next evenings :-(

Answer (score 0):

you nested loop to fill or read your multi-dimension matrix:

```
int matrix [a] [b];

for(int i(0); i != a; ++i)
    for(int j(0); j != b; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = i * j;
```

Or to fill it with input from user:

```
for(int i(0); i != a; ++i)
    for(int j(0); j != b; ++j){
        std::cout << "matrix[" << i << "][" << j <<
            "]: ";
        std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
```

To print it:

```
for(int i(0); i != a; ++i){
    for(int j(0); j != b; ++j)
        std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use memset function

```
int matrix[n+1][n+1];
memset(matrix,0,sizeof(dp));`
```

Comment: this is incorrect. the elements of the matrix are integers, this only works by accident when you set the bytes of the integers to 0 with memset. this will not work when memsetting other values.